# How to draw a chart from database (JPA)

Tags: mysql, ajax, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to draw some charts with Highcharts library, values are driven from database(JPA), without having any errors all I'm getting is this json output and no graph. I know I haven't returned to jsp page where the Graph container is, if that's the reason can someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

json output

```
    {"month":[6,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9],"student":[6,600,696,697,698,701,726,727,728,729,730,803]}
```

controller

```
    @GetMapping("/userChart")
    @ResponseBody
    public String UserJoinedInstitution(HttpSession session) {
        
        Integer insId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("instId");
        List<Users> userlist = us.getAllStudentsFromInstitution(insId);
        JsonArray month = new JsonArray();
        JsonArray student = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        userlist.forEach(user->{
            Date date = user.getCreatedDate();
            LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            int m = localDate.getMonthValue();
            
            month.add(m);
            student.add(user.getUserId());
        });
        json.add("month", month);
        json.add("student", student);
        
        return json.toString();
    }
```

JScript

```
    var chart = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/userChart',
            success: function(result){
                    var month = JSON.parse(result).month;
                    var student = JSON.parse(result).student;
                    drawChart(month, student);
            }
        })

        function drawChart(month, student){
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 15,
                    beta: 0,
                    depth: 100,
                    viewDistance: 15
                }
            },
                title: {
                    text: 'Line Chart'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    depth: 25
                }
            },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: month
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function(){
                        return '<strong>'+this.x+': </strong>'+this.y;
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: student
                }]
            });
        }
    });
```

JSP

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you have any `JS` error ?

Comment: That's what I'm getting in JS consol `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: Hi , first parse your json i.e : `var jsons = JSON.parse(result)` and then access month like this `var month =jsons.month` same for other as well . Here is [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/v23grknw/1/)

Comment: Thank you Swati hardcoded value works for me too but how do I take the database values from controller to jQuery/Ajax ?

Comment: Does response from backend come successfully ? i.e :`result` ?

Comment: Thank you Swati you helped again.   :-)